# How to convert of Stream of Mono to Flux or reduce a stream of Mono to a Mono using sum operation

Tags: spring-webflux

My code is as below. I need to get a fare from mongo db for each trip, and then sum all the fares for each trip to get the total fare. I am stuck with a stream of Mono that I do not know how to read from. I tried converting this to a Flux, but I am getting a Flux<Mono>, which is not what I want. Please help!! Or how can we reduce a Stream of Mono to a Mono?

```
private int calculateDailyRate(final Entry<LocalDate, List<Trip>> entry) {
        int dailyFare = 0;
        List<Trip> trips = entry.getValue();
        // Get the fare for each trip, and then sum up the list of fares to get the daily total fare        
        trips.stream().map(trip->fareLookupRepo.getFareRules(trip.getSecondOfDay(), trip.getTripDate().getDayOfWeek().getValue(),
                    trip.getFromZone(), trip.getToZone()).sort(Comparator.comparing(FareRule::getRate)).next().map(FareRule::getRate));
        return dailyFare;
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your logic is correct, because your can be dates with entires.

But here is hint how to do what you try to achive.

```
  return Flux.fromIterable(trips)
            .flatMap(trip-> fareLookupRepo.getFareRules(trip.getSecondOfDay(), trip.getTripDate().getDayOfWeek().getValue(),
                    trip.getFromZone(), trip.getToZone())
            .flatMap(trip-> Mono.just(trip.getRate())))
            .reduce(0, (x1, x2)-> x1 + x2)
```

Note: `fareLookupRepo.getFareRules` it should return mono

Comment: Thanks!! This seems to work . I modified it as below to get it working: Flux.fromIterable(trips).flatMap(trip->getMatchingFareRule(trip).map(FareRule::getRate)).reduce(0, (x1, x2)-> x1 + x2) where getMatchingFareRule returns Mono<FareRule>

Comment: Happy to help :) If it helps please accept my answer ;) @Gayathri